# Cordova 404 on js files 3 levels down

Tags: javascript, cordova, http-status-code-404

I am using Cordova with a Browser build. Project consists of a html page plus many js files in a directory structure 3 levels deep. I get 404 error for all script tags referencing files in the third level. All other script tags work ok. The project works fine outside of Cordova. I have checked all similar Cordova 404 problems on StackOverflow. Most refer to whitelist which I have checked/changed/re-checked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an unused level 3 Test directory I had in my source. When I ran: cordova run browser, it silently choked on this directory and then stopped copying any more directories.

I removed the Test directory and all worked fine.

Sure, I am an idiot for not noticing this to start with but since I wasted so much time on it I thought I would post this to help others.